# What is the convention: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=-i $ or $i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am not sure about this:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\frac1i=-i $$

or

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}=i $$

?

I would say the second but Wolfram Mathematica says

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\frac1i=-i $$

What is the convention?

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\sqrt{i}$ defines globally the pair of solutions to equation $z^2+1=0$. Computer Algebra Systems make a choice, but this choice is not engraved in marble stone.

Comment: @JeanMarie you mean Sqrt[-1] ?

Comment: If you say $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}$ so $1=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=ii=i^2=-1$

Comment: @Mencia Yes my bad Sqrt[-1]

Comment: Could you explain why you would choose the second?

Answer (score 2):

Let $i=\sqrt {-1}$.

From $i\cdot i=-1$ divide both sides by $i$ to obtain $i=-\frac 1i$

You need to make a consistent choice of sign, because there are two possible square roots $i$ and $-i$. To avoid errors, use a notation which enforces this.

Answer (score 2):

This question strikingly shows what calamity is the notation $\sqrt{-1}$. There is no such mathematical object, and the notation $\sqrt{\phantom{a}}$ should be used exclusively for its original aim: denote the positive square root of a *positive real number*. In all other contexts, we cannot distinguish between the `two` square roots of a *complex* number

Comment: According to you, what should Wolfram Mathematica do when there is something like $1/ \sqrt{-f^2}$ for real $f$ ?

Comment: I really don't know, as this depends very much on the context: in Number theory, one often meets things like $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, but there is no ambiguity,as it denotes any element satisfying he equation $x^2+3=0$, and it is more of a symbolic, not to say metaphoric, notation. I suppose Mathematica (which I don't use) knows this usage).

Comment: I think that Mathematica's algorithm when dealing with fractional roots (say, $1/n$) of negative numbers is to take the fractional root of the absolute value and multiply by the $2n$th root of unity with smallest positive argument. This applies whether $n$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the powers of $i$ are cyclic.

$$\color{red}{i^0=1}$$
$$\color{blue}{i^1=i}$$
$$\color{green}{i^2=-1}$$
$$\color{orange}{i^3=-i}$$
$$\color{red}{i^4=1}$$
$$\color{blue}{i^5=i}$$
$$...$$

This pattern also applies for negative powers.

$$\color{red}{i^{-4}=1}$$
$$\color{blue}{i^{-3}=i}$$
$$\color{green}{i^{-2}=-1}$$
$$\color{orange}{i^{-1}=-i}$$

Therefore, it is easy to deduce that the result of $i^{2017}=i$ is for example, as well as $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ just by dividing the power by $4$ and looking at the remainder obtained.

Answer (score 1):

The typographical picture $\sqrt{-1}$ does not define a mathematical entity, but is the formulation of a problem. Therefore it makes no sense to write things like ${1\over\sqrt{-1}}$ or even $e^{\sqrt{-1}\,\phi}$.

When we write "Let $i=\sqrt{-1}$" this is a colloquial expression of the agreement that henceforth $i$ is a constant satisfying $i^2=-1$.

In any case one has ${1\over i}=-i$. This is **not a convention** but a stringent consequence from $i^2=-1$ and the field axioms valid in the "complex environment".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I asked about the convention, I was not referring to 1/i=-i. I was referring to 1/Sqrt[-1]=i vs 1/Sqrt[-1]=-i.

Comment: According to you, what should Wolfram Mathematica do when there is something like $1/ \sqrt{- f^2}$ for real $f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we have some negative term in square root. Its not good practice to solve it like you are solving in method 2.

You have to replace -1 into $i^2$.

> Edit -

Product Rule (extended) -

$\sqrt{ab} =  \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$

where a ≥ 0, b ≥ 0 Or a ≥ 0, b < 0

But NOT a < 0, b < 0

So $\sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1} \ne 1$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apparently that is what Wolfram Mathematica does. Is that something well established among mathematicians?

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope now its clears to you.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to what other said, we can say for $i=0+i=(0,1)\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\frac{1}{0+i}=\frac{1}{0+i}\times\frac{0-i}{0-i}=\frac{-i}{(-1,0)}{\color{red}\equiv}\frac{-i}{-1}=i$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{C}$ is a field, so exist $a , b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{i} = a + i b$. We will show that $a = 0$ and $b = - 1$. We have that
$$
\frac{1}{i} = a + i b \Longleftrightarrow 1 = i (a + i b) = i a + i^2 b = - b + i a\mbox{,}
$$
so, taking real and imaginary parts,
$$
Re (a i - b) = Re 1 \Longleftrightarrow - b = 1 \mbox{ and } Im (a i - b) = Im 1 \Longleftrightarrow a = 0\mbox{,}
$$
because of this $a = 0$ and $b = - 1$.